# How to change login database in sample C# ASP.NET application (webforms, non MVC)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been searching for days on how to change the login system on the ASP.NET webforms template application (the default project you get in visual studio 2012) from a LocalDB to a SQL 2012 Express server.

Here is what I have done so far:
1) copied schema from localDB to SQL Express instance
2) added SQL Express instance to SQL Server Object Explorer and Server explorer
3) removed all traces of the localdb from the SQL Server Object Explorer

To my suprise, all of the test login accounts I created against the localDB still work, and a SELECT statement issued via Management Studio reveals that the SQL Express instance does not have any users in it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, did you also modify the connection string in `web.config` to point away from the localDb and to your SQL Express instance?

Comment: That fixed it! When I first searched through it, I just assumed that Web.Config was not clickable, and I didnt find anything in Web.Debug.Config or Web.Release.Config

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the ASP.Net Configuration (In your visual studio click Project => ASP.Net Configuration) and follow their steps